# Add buttons to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I would like to add buttons to an UIView. The number of buttons varies from view to view. 
I want to achieve the following:

[image: Buttons in UIView]

I tried to add the Buttons (in a foreach construct) like this:

```
UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
[but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:but];
```

But I don't know how to calculate the CGRectMake when it comes to an new line. How can I check the end of the line (UIView)? Or is it kinda stupid to add Buttons like this?

Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add calculate buttons size after you set the title. Then keep track of the current X and Y of the previous buttons and figure out if the newly created button can fit on the current "line". Otherwise go to the next one.

I suggest you to look at existing components and see how they do it, below are a couple links.

https://github.com/domness/DWTagList

https://github.com/andreamazz/AMTagListView

Answer (score 0):

With the following code , you can place multiple buttons in one row as long as their total width and the gap is smaller then the view's width.

```
 UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *allBtns = nil;
    float viewWidth;

    float currentY = 0;
    float currentX = 0;
    float btnGapWidth = 10.0;
    float btnGapHeight = 2.0;
    for (UIButton *btn in allBtns) {
        CGRect rc = btn.frame;
        BOOL shouldAddToNewLine = viewWidth - currentX - btnGapWidth < rc.size.width ? YES : NO;

        if (shouldAddToNewLine) {
            rc.origin = CGPointMake(0, currentY + rc.size.height + btnGapHeight);
            currentX = 0;
            currentY += rc.size.height + btnGapHeight;
        } else {
            //another row
            rc.origin = CGPointMake(currentX + rc.size.width + btnGapWidth, currentY);
            currentX += rc.size.width + btnGapWidth;
        }
        btn.frame = rc;
        [view addSubview:btn];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dee - your code works for buttons with the same frame size (width). I tried to add the UIButtons within the for loop and set the title (with [aButton setTitle:[stringArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];) After that I tried to set the UIButton frame (aButton) with: [aButton sizeToFit]; I leave the rest of your code as it is and now I got some overlapping buttons. Thanks for your help :)